# Coding challenge on keyframes and hover

Tags: html, css

I need to apply transitions to the CSS so that the coloured squares **open-up** when the `div` **main** is hovered. To **open-up** each square should rotate 90 degrees by its outer-most corner.

This is what I have so far. Not sure how to get them all to move at the same time. There is supposed to be text in the middle that makes them move when you hover over it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwJNp.png)

```css
.container{
   
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: solid;
    margin-top: 200;
    margin: auto;

}



.red{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: move 4s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move{
    0%{


    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: top left;
    }
}

.yellow{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    animation: moveYellow 4s;
    animation-play-state: paused;

   
}

@keyframes moveYellow{
    0%{


    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: top right;
    }
}

.blue{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color:blue;
    animation: moveBlue 4s;
    animation-play-state: paused;

   
}

@keyframes moveBlue{
    0%{


    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: bottom left;
    }
}

.green{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
    animation: moveGreen 4s;
    animation-play-state: paused;

}

.red:hover, .blue:hover, .yellow:hover, .green:hover{
    animation-play-state: running;
}



@keyframes moveGreen{
    0%{


    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: bottom right;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div> 
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
    
        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take your assignment word by word, there is everything you need: `Apply transitions` so you'll need `transitions`, here you use *animations*...  `When the div main is hovered.` here you are listening to each squares hover, not the main one. And for the final `should rotate 90 degrees by its outer-most corner` just means they should all have their own `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply transitions to `div#main:hover` where each box in the square will have its own movement 
**CSS File could look like this**

```
div#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
div#main .topleft {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: red;
}
div#main:hover .topleft {
     transform:rotate(-90deg);
     transition: 2s;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     margin: -25px;

}
```

This is just a small sample but can give you the idea on how to handle the rest of the boxes to do the animation you want to.

Comment: "could" not "should". It can all be done in a more DRY style.